# Third Party Cookies - Cross Domain APIs w/ Session Tracking

Tags: api, session, cookies, cross-domain

Given a CORS API that requires a session cookie to track users as they move through a checkout process, there are issues in multiple browsers where the cookie is not set until after the user visits the site the API is hosted on.

**For example:**

> johnny.com uses an CORS JSON API from jacob.com. jacob.com sets a
>   cookie after the first AJAX call is made, but some browsers will not
>   set the cookie for subsequent calls. Therefore the API will not
>   function as expected.

**Browser Behavior:**

- Chrome seems to function fine unless "Third-Party cookies" are
  deliberately disabled. There doesn't seem to be a workaround for
  this.
- IE does not allow the cookie to be set initially unless there is a P3P privacy policy header returned with the initial call.
- Safari does not allow the cookie to be set initially unless a hack is used (see: http://measurablewins.gregjxn.com/2014/02/safari-setting-third-party-iframe.html)

Any insight on how to work around these issues is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same situation right now. Have you found a solution that fits your needs?

Comment: The best solution I've seen is to create a ton of iframes that load and manage data from the other domain. This requires additional header modification so the site allows iframes from other domains.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Do cookies work in iframes even if the frame loads another domain?

Comment: Yes. I've never personally run into an issue with cookies within an iframe. As long as the iframe loads, the cookies work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems there are not option to make that work across all browsers.

Safari [now restricts](https://webkit.org/blog/7675/intelligent-tracking-prevention/) third party use of cookies.
It seems the best is to evaluate alternatives :

- Setup a proxy server that will redirect the calls to the different services (for example, when you hit johnny.com/jacob/abc, act as proxy to retrieve jacob.com/abc)
- Use oauth login on API (it might be impractical)
- Move the API under johnny.com/api/...

Paypal has also created several js based solutions to try to go around this kind of problems : https://medium.com/@bluepnume/introducing-paypals-open-source-cross-domain-javascript-suite-95f991b2731d